# Canonicalize URL to lowercase without breaking file system or culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winapi

## Canonicalizing URLs to Lowercase

I wish to write an HTTP module that converts URLs to lowercase. My first attempt ignored international character sets and works great:

```
// Convert URL virtual path to lowercase
string lowercase = context.Request.FilePath.ToLowerInvariant();

// If anything changed then issue 301 Permanent Redirect
if (!lowercase.Equals(context.Request.FilePath, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    context.Response.RedirectPermanent(...lowercase URL...);
}
```

## The Turkey Test (international cultures):

But what about cultures other than en-US? I referred to the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) to come up with a test URL:

```
http://example.com/Iıİi
```

This little insidious gem destroys any notion that case conversion in URLs is simple! Its lowercase and uppercase versions, respectively, are:

```
http://example.com/ııii
http://example.com/IIİİ
```

For case conversion to work with Turkish URLs, I first had to set the current culture of ASP.NET to Turkish:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="tr-TR" />
</system.web>
```

Next, I had to change my code to use the current culture for the case conversion:

```
// Convert URL virtual path to lowercase
string lowercase = context.Request.FilePath.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

// If anything changed then issue 301 Permanent Redirect
if (!lowercase.Equals(context.Request.FilePath, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    context.Response.RedirectPermanent(...);
}
```

But wait! Will `StringComparison.Ordinal` still work? Or should I use `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`? I'm really not certain of either!

## File names: It gets MUCH WORSE!

Even if the above works, using the current culture for case conversions *breaks* the NTFS file system! Let's say I have a static file with the name `Iıİi.html`:

```
http://example.com/Iıİi.html
```

Even though the Windows file system is case-insensitive it does not use language culture. Converting the above URL to lowercase results in a 404 Not Found because the file system doesn't consider the two names as equal:

```
http://example.com/ııii.html
```

## The correct case conversion for file names? WHO KNOWS?!

The MSDN article, [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx), has a note (about halfway through the article):

> **Note:**
>   The string behavior of the file system, registry keys and values, and environment variables is best represented by StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

Huh? *Best represented???* Is that the best we can do in C#? So just what is the correct case conversion to match the file system? **Who knows?!!?** About all we can say is that string comparisons using the above will probably work MOST of the time.

## Summary: Two case conversions: Static/Dynamic URLs

1. So we've seen that **static URLs**---URLs having a file path that matches a real directory/file in the file system---must use an unknown case conversion that is only "best represented" by `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. And please note there is no `string.ToLowerOrdinal()` method so it's very difficult to know exactly what case conversion equates to the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` string comparison. Using `string.ToLowerInvariant()` is probably the best bet, yet it breaks language culture.
2. On the other hand, **dynamic URLs**---URLs with a file path that does not match a real file on the disk (that map to your application)---can use `string.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`, but it breaks file system matching and it is somewhat unclear what edge cases exist that may break this strategy.

Thus, it appears case conversion first requires detection as to whether a URL is static or dynamic before choosing one of two conversion methods. For static URLs there is uncertainty how to change case without breaking the Windows file system. For dynamic URLs it is questionable if case conversion using culture will similarly break the URL.

Whew! Anyone have a solution to this mess? Or should I just close my eyes and pretend everything is ASCII?

Comment: As far as I understand the safe case for lower/uppercase conversion is probably only the basic latin alphabet. Unicode includes many language, some may even don't have such a thing as uppercase letters. That way you probably can only use exact matches for any codepoint above 127.

Comment: @John Converting basic Latin would be a conservative solution, yet .NET provides no `.ToLowerASCII()` that only affects those characters. The `.ToLowerInvariant()` goes much further and decimates many international characters. I'm certain there is no 100% solution at this point.

Comment: @KevinR considered trying enumerating the files manually and using the value in `Accept-Language`? `String.ToLower` is also a nasty bag of worms when you are using it for comparisons. Let me figure out how to do a culture case-insensitive compare.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I am not using `Accept-Language`. `CurrentCulture` refers to the configuration of the server side application only (unless you make that track Accept-Language). One would expect a server with Turkish URLs to be set to that culture, though I suppose a nightmare scenario could exist with multiple culture URLs on one machine. Perhaps John is right to only convert ASCII characters.

Comment: @KevinR I would avoid each URL culture being culture aware. Even though it was written in, say, English the user might still be Turkish and would apply their own casing rules. Current user trumps the creator in this case.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I don't understand why a user's Turkish casing rules should be applied on a server with English URLs---or vice-versa. It seems to me that user culture has nothing to do with it, unless the server is providing URLs for each language.

Comment: @KevinR it's a UX judgement call - at the end of the day if you settle on a single culture other cultures might have problems. From your perspective, imagine typing in an English URL to a Turkish server (messing up the casing) and getting a 404: how should the user know what culture the server is running in? "I am trying to use the website and therefore my culture wins."

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I think I understand your point, which would apply if I were providing a Turkish UX. I don't. Thus a UA set to Turkish requesting `/INFO` should follow MY culture rules and canonicalize to `/info` not `/ınfo` which would 404. Similarly, a user that speaks Turkish but using an en-US browser at a library and requesting `/III` on a Turkish server should probably canonicalize to `/ııı`. Hence: (1) The user culture only matters if culture specific URLs and UX are available. (2) A user's culture cannot be guaranteed from the UA culture (`Accept-Language`). A judgment call, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some incompatible goals.

1. Have a culture-sensitive case-lowering. If Turkish seems bad, you don't want to know about some of the Georgian scripts, never mind that `ß` is either upper-cased to `SS` or less commonly to `SZ` - in either case to have a full case-folding where `lower("ß")` will match `lower(upper("ß"))` you need to consider it equivalent to at least one of those two-character sequences. Generally we aim for case-folding rather than case-lowering if possible (not possible here).
2. Use this in a non culture-sensitive context. URIs are ultimately opaque strings. That they *may* have a human-readable understanding is usefulful for coders, users, search-engines and marketers alike, but their ultimate job is to identify a resource by a direct case-sensitive comparison.
3. Map this to NTFS, which has a case-preserving case-sensitivity based on the mappings in the $UpCase file, which it does by comparing the *upper-cased* forms of words (at least it doesn't have to decide whether `Σ` lower-cases to `σ` or `ς`, in a culture-insensitive manner.
4. Presumably do well in terms of SEO and human readability. This may well be part of your original goal, but whileThisIsNotVeryEasyToReadOrParse itseasierforbothpeopleandmachinesthanthis. Case-folding loses information.

I suggest a different approach.

1. Start with your starting string, whatever that is and wherever it came from (NTFS filename, database entry, HttpHandler binding in web.config). Have that as your canonical form. By all means have rules that people should create these strings according to some canonical form, and perhaps enforce it where you can, but if something slips by that breaks your rules, then accept it as the official canonical name for that resource no matter how much you dislike it.
2. As much as possible the canonical name should be the only one "seen" by the outside world. This can be enforced programmatically or just a matter of it being best practice, as canonicalising after the fact with 301s won't solve the fact that outside entities don't know you do so until they dereference the URI.
3. When a request is received, test it according to how it is going to be used. Hence while you may choose to use a particular culture (or not) for those cases where you perform the resource-lookup yourself, with so-called "static" URIs, your logic can deliberately follow that of NTFS by simply using NTFS to do the work:

   1. Find mapped file ignoring the matter of case sensitivity for now.
   2. If non-match then 404, who cares about case?
   3. If find, do case-sensitive ordinal comparison, if it doesn't match then 301 to the case-sensitive mapping.
   4. Otherwise, proceed as usual.

Edit:

In some ways the question of domain names is more complicated. The rules for IDN have to cover more issues with less room for manœuver. However, it's also simpler at least as far as case-canonicalising goes.

(I'm going to ignore canonicalising of whether or not `www.` is used etc. though I'd guess it's part of the same job here, it's pushing the scope and we could end up writing a book between us if we don't stop somewhere :)

IDNs have their own case canoniclisation (and some other forms of normalisation) rules defined in RFC 3491. If you're going to canonicalise domain names on case, follow that.

Makes it nice and simple to answer, doesn't it? :)

There's also less pressure in a way, for while search engines have to recognise that `http://example.net/thisisapath` and `http://example.net/thisIsAPath` may be the same resource, they also have to recognise that they might be different, and that's where all of the SEO advantage of canonicalising on one of them (doesn't matter which) comes from.

However, they know that `example.net` and `EXAMPLE.NET` can't possibly be different sites, so there's little SEO advantage in making sure they're the same (still nice for things like caches and history lists that don't make that jump themselves). Of course, the issue remains with the fact that `www.example.net` or even `maAndPasExampleEmporium.us` might be the same site, but again, that moves away from case issues.

There's also the simple matter that most of the time we never have to deal with more than a couple of dozen different domains, so sometimes working harder rather than smarter (i.e. just make sure they're all set up right and don't do anything programmatically!) can do the trick.

A final note though, it's important not to canonicalise a third-party URI. You can end up breaking things if you change the path (they may not be treating it case-insensitively) and you might at least end up breaking their slightly different canonicalisation. Best to leave them as is at all times.

Comment: Indeed, goal incompatibility becomes apparent when pursuing a precise solution. Interestingly, no incompatibility exists within the ASCII character set making the goals appear easily attainable. My intent is to produce code to canonicalize host name (www and .org/net/us), letter case, trailing slash and more, primarily for SEO. Individual features can be disabled. A combination of your suggested approach, and moderate canonicalization seems reasonable to provide SEO and 404-avoidance for bad incoming links, CAPS-LOCK typists, canonical domain, etc. No? I like your arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the lack of incompatibility within ASCII exists because of the limitations of ASCII in dealing with such cases (unless you use some obsolete control codes, which brings them back and more). I can think of a case though, *nathair* and *NATHAIR* means *snake* in Irish, but *nAthair* would be "father" as it would appear in some contexts (capitalised to *nATHAIR* or *N-ATHAIR*). I ignored domain names which have different issues. I'll add more on that later when I've time.

Comment: You worldly knowledge is most elucidating. I look forward to your comments on domain names. Typically, it's just matter of redirecting multiple TLDs to '.com'. I very much like S.O.'s approach of providing a unique article ID followed by an SEO title which is unimportant to accessing the page. No matter what you type after the article ID the right page is found. Yet, S.O. still redirects to the canonical URL. I'm very curious what S.O. does with any of the non-ASCII characters as case-lowering is implemented.

Answer (score 5):

I would challenge the premise here that there is any utility whatsoever in attempting to auto-convert URLs to lowercase.

Whether a full URL is case-sensitive or not depends *entirely* on the web server, web application framework, and underlying file system.

You're only *guaranteed* case-insensitivity in the scheme (http://, etc.) and hostname portions of the URL. And remember that not all URL schemes (`file` and `news`, for example) even include a hostname.

Everything else can be case-sensitive to the server, including paths (`/`), filenames, queries (`?`), fragments (`#`), and authority info (usernames/passwords before the `@` in `mailto`, `http`, `ftp`, and some other schemes).

Comment: I have considered that premise strongly. Yet SEO best practices encourage a singular lowercase URL as well as responsiveness to inadvertent uppercase equivalents. There must be a pleasant middle ground. Note, I am only addressing the path, not any other portion of the URL. Also, in my testing, fragments (#) are not transmitted to the server, and are contained to the user agent.

Comment: As a freanch (one of these strange people that use a lot of accented characters and even more exotic ones as 'ç'), I'm not at all surprised to have URLs whithout automatic conversion to ASCII lowercase. I guess Turkish people would feel the same, so there is little point in having that feature, especially as getting it right is really a pain for all the reasons you detailled.

Comment: @Falanwe Let me be clear that I am not advocating the conversion of accented characters to plain ASCII. Let me ask: Do you prefer French URLs to be responsive to both upper & lowercase French accented equivalents? StackOverflow does lowercase canonicalization. W.W.S.O.D.?

Comment: As a french, I'm used to have the url non-accented, non-capitalized. In fact, when a site is responsive to accented characters, I tend to be surprised! Special characters are usually encoded into %number, which make some ugly urls.

Comment: @Falanwe Would you expect `http://fleurs.fr/EXPÉDITION` and `http://fleurs.fr/expédition` to access the same web page? And what about `http://fleurs.fr/expedition`? Thanks.

Comment: richardtallent, the problem comes precisely from that lack of guarantee. Someone writes a few different forms of the URI because it's backed by a case-insensitive system, and then the outside world has too assume they are different URIs because that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @KévinR: I would expect http://fleurs.fr/EXPÉDITION and http://fleurs.fr/expédition to be aliases for http://fleurs.fr/expedition. But I would not be surprised if it turned to http://fleurs/exp%C3%A9dition due to encoding. That's why French people are not used to have accents in URL (and hardly ever capitalized accented character as we hardly ever use them: to make an 'É', I have to copy-paste it as it's not anywhere on my keyboard and I don't know its utf8 number ^^)

Comment: @richardtallent Thanks for weighing in with a worthy challenge and thoughts. This exercise has convinced me that chasing strict SEO ideals is overkill. Yet, I believe restrained canonicalization is still a worthy goal. You can see canonicalization used here on S.O. for instance. I do find utility in redirecting CAPS-LOCK-URLS along with domain name correction to provide users some 404 resilience. Seeking purism toward either extreme may be too aggressive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **never** use case transformations to compare strings. It needlessly allocates a string, it has a needless small performance impact, could result in an `ObjectReferenceException` if the value is null and could likely result in an incorrect comparison.

If this is important enough to you I would manually traverse the file system and use the your own comparisons against each file/directory name. You should be able to use `Accept-Language` or `Accept-Encoding` (if it has a culture included) HTTP header to find the suitable culture to use. Once you have the `CultureInfo` you can use it to perform the string comparisons:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; // Use Accept-Language to derive this.
ci.CompareInfo.Compare("The URL", "the url", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I would only do this on a HTTP 404; the HTTP 404 handler would search for a matching file and then HTTP 301 the user to the correctly-cased URL (as manual file-system traversal can get expensive).

Comment: The case transformation represents the canonical path. Without a case transformation there is nothing to compare to; and, if the comparison does not match, the case transformation is the string used to build the 301 URL. Without a case transformation, the only other option would be to iterate the URL path characters checking for `char.IsUpper()`. And you'd *still* have to transform the case if you found a true case.

Comment: @KevinR I garnered your files are on disk (and not, say, DB records) - which makes the first sentence of the second paragraph very important. Your canonical path is the path as described as by the file system.

Comment: >>"Your canonical path is the path as described as by the file system" Yep, that already occurred to me. I could 301 to the file system's letter case or follow SEO practice which encourages lowercase and ignore the file system. Or, one could write an app that transforms all the file names on disk to lowercase. I have applications with both static files and dynamic URLs, thus `!File.Exists()` would trigger the dynamic URL casing rules.

Comment: @KevinR don't use `File.Exists()` manually iterate over the files according to the URL and use `CompareInfo.Compare` - this is what I meant.